# Store hash information for drop-down selection

Tags: javascript

I'm guessing I am going to need to make a cookie for this, but let me know if there is another way. I have a dropdown menu that uses link elements to select a language on the site, depending on which link element they select, a hash is created an appended to the end of the URL. I am looking for a way to store this selection so that the selection remains across all pages instead of resetting each time they refresh or leave the page.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="menu cid">
   <a href="#" title="en">United States</a>
   <a href="#" title="can">Canada</a>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  if(document.location.hash == ""){ 
    location.href = location.href + "#en";
  }
});

jQuery('.menu a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var clickedAnchor = jQuery(this),
        countryID = clickedAnchor.attr('title');

    location.href = location.href.split('#')[0] + '#' + countryID;
    location.reload();

});

var countryID = window.location.hash;
countryID = countryID.substring(1);
console.log("country code: "+countryID);

var countryID = "en";
    if (document.location.hash != "") {
       countryID = document.location.hash.substring(1);
    } 
    var map = {"en":"4242", "can":"4243"};
    cii_EmbedProductLinks('Chairs','{{ prodID }}',map[countryID], CI_LinkID);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Possible solutions are,

- **cookies** - if you require client side implementation, take care with the expiration
- **html5 web storage (local storage, session storage)** - client side only and if you do not have a restriction for not using html5. I think session storage is better for your case, since it will keep the settings until the user's session is expired.
- **server session** - if you are going to serve content based on the value selected i.e. the language, this is better suited. This is commonly used by systems supporting i18n that need to know the language chosen at any time at both server and client side.

Answer (score 1):

I hate when people just paste in links but this is all I can do for now:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Sorry, I hope this helps!